# Bind one NSTextField to multiple properties

Tags: swift, multi-select, appkit

I am trying to do multiple edits in an Inspector View, I have two objects selected and I would like to edit both of their houseName properties at the same time.

```
class House: NSObject {
    dynamic var houseName: String
}

var house1: House()
var house2: House()

houseNameTextField.bind(.value, to: house1, withKeyPath: "houseName", options: [])
```

If I bind the first house, I can change the property fine, however, can I bind a second property to the same textField, so when I edit the textfield, both properties get updated?

Calling .bind again simply overwrites the first binding

Comment: Do you want to bind a second property or do you want to bind to a second object? If the values are different, which value should be displayed?

Comment: I've seen before when editing multiple properties at once, a textfield will display "multiple" and then whatever value you enter will override them both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me, I needed to create an ArrayController and use the "selection" key, it magically works

```
let options: [NSBindingOption : Any] = [NSBindingOption.validatesImmediately: true,
                                        NSBindingOption.allowsEditingMultipleValuesSelection: true,
                                        NSBindingOption.multipleValuesPlaceholder: "Multiple",
                                        NSBindingOption.nullPlaceholder: "None",
                                        NSBindingOption.conditionallySetsEditable: true]

houseNameTextField.bind(.value, to: arrayController, withKeyPath: "selection.houseName", options: options)
```

Comment: Note: this is a binding to one property of multiple objects. Not a binding to multiple properties.